# Argument exception when I try to set a variable with a custom set in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried to use the `Generate()` function only if a variable has changed without having to check it every frame. I used the following [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V3fXY-clRjg) to achieve this. but for some reason, whenever i try to set the variable, I get this error:

> ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'List`1' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.

the script:

```
public GameObject CEMM;

private int ListLength;

public static int ListLengthProperty
{
    get
    {
        return JLSV.instance.ListLength;
    }
    set
    {
        JLSV.instance.ListLength = value;
        JLSV.instance.Generate();
    }
}

private void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
}
```

I tried to set the value like this: `JLScrollView.ListLengthProperty = JLScrollView.instance.CEMM.GetComponent<List<JLClass>>().Count;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic type parameter that you use when calling [GetComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) must be a class that derives from Component (or an interface type). [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0) is a plain old class object, which is why you are getting the exception from this:

```
GetComponent<List<JLClass>>()
```

I'm not really sure what value you are trying to assign to the property. If you are trying to get the number of components of a certain type on the GameObject you can use [GetComponents](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponents.html).

```
JLScrollView.ListLengthProperty = JLScrollView.instance.GetComponents<JLClass>().Length;
```

Comment: ah, my mistake. I meant to add `CEMM` before `GetComponent`. `CEMM` contains a list and I was trying to set that list's `.Count` as the int.

Comment: Right yeah that makes more sense. In that case you'd need to write something like this: `JLScrollView.ListLengthProperty = JLScrollView.instance.CEMM.List.Count;`.